# Script to monitor CPU

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=`hostname`
THRESHOLD=20
CPU_USAGE=`/usr/sbin/sar -u 4 | awk '{print $5}'| grep -v '%idle'` ;
while
[[ $CPU_USAGE -gt $THRESHOLD ]]; do
logger -p local0.alert "$HOSTNAME CPU usage is idle"
done
```

May I know if there is any problem when run script to return  syntax error in expression (error token is "74")?

Comment: works for me... change `/usr/sbin/sar` to `sar`, still it would just throw an error about non existant binary; still `sar -u 4 | awk '{print $5}'| grep -v '%idle'` won't return anything, ever; and generally using while with interactive command that never ends is just useless; not to mention that `$5` is `%nice`

Comment: Add `set -x` before assigning to HOSTNAME to show which commands are executed. I would delete the newline after `while` for readability.

Comment: You can probably get rid of the while loop and the grep and do everything in awk.

Comment: HOSTNAME=`hostname`
THRESHOLD=20
CPU_USAGE=`sar -u 4 | awk '{print $5}'`
if [[ $CPU_USAGE -gt $THRESHOLD ]]; then
 echo "$HOSTNAME CPU usage is idle"
#logger -p local0.alert "$HOSTNAME CPU usage is idle"
fi
exit 0

Comment: i have no idea the reason the error toaken is 75 show on script every time.  Please advice